# How to create a matrix from two csv columns in google sheets?

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I am using a google form to input data to a google spreadsheet. I have two columns that contain data in CSV format.

I would like to use a formula to generate a matrix that represents the count of each items occurrence and totals for each row/column.

I ave tried the example formulas from this thread https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3vXh-NNtgW8 but the logic breaks when there are multiple values in column B.

Here is a sheet with example data from the pictures above.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HHBTV8zTZs2xlGudta1o05b_zX21b5I3KRrBLo__kpo/edit#gid=450392226

Thanks!

Comment: Google Sheets or Excel? You have both tags attributed to your question. While they have similarities, they are not the same thing.

Comment: Would it be possible to get editing rights on the sheet ? I would love to try something out.. :-)

Comment: @JPV I just gave editing access to anyone with the link. Please feel free to give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: @Jeeped I am currently using a google sheet as the data comes from a google form. I know there are many differences between excel and gsheets, but there are also many similar functions. I should have specified in the question but if there is a simple solution in Excel I can always paste the data into an excel workbook to form the matrix as a last resort. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EaRhMxia9JTuwXsLchcewQq18FFHJnpk4seX7l6Hyvg/edit?usp=sharing) I tried to offer two solutions. Note that the formulas are very convoluted, but the centerpiece is:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({transpose(split(join(",",trim(transpose(split(query(rept(A2:A5&char(9),len(substitute(B2:B5,",",""))),,5000),char(9))))),",")), transpose(split(QUERY(rept(transpose(split(query(B2:B5&",",,rows(B2:B5)),","))&char(9),  len(substitute(trim(transpose(split(query(rept(A2:A5&char(9),len(substitute(B2:B5,",",""))),,5000),char(9)))),",","")  )),,50000),char(9)))&{"","",""}}, "select Col1, Count(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3") )
```

In the first solution the totals are calculated separately with MMULT (see sheet), referencing the table outputted by the above formula. E.g:

```
=arrayFormula({"Total", transpose(mmult(transpose(if(isblank((F2:J7)),0,(F2:J7))),row(F2:F7)^0))})
```

EDIT/UPDATE (after first comment of OP)

For a solution that is certainly easier to maintain, consider following steps:

1. Get all unique fruits(vertically):

   =ArrayFormula(unique(trim(transpose(split(query('Data from CSV Columns'!A2:A&",",,50000),",")))))
2. Get all unique names (horizontally):

   =ArrayFormula(transpose(unique(transpose(trim(split(query('Data from CSV Columns'!B2:B&",",,50000),","))))))

   3. Now fill the table with the counts.. next to the first fruit and under the first name:

   =COUNTIF(filter('Data from CSV Columns'!$A$2:$A, regexmatch('Data from CSV Columns'!$B$2:$B,I$1 )),"*"&$H2&"*")

where I1 is the first name  and H2 is the first fruit.

4. Drag this last formula down and to the right to suit.

An example of these steps is visible [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rSjIagq9l8b7P55xCsfJBlCzfHsIOKTZ1DH59fQIlbk/edit?usp=sharing)
Note that the list with names and fruits will automatically expand when new forms are submitted. Only the COUNTIF-formula will need to be dragged down...

Comment: JPV this looks like exactly what I want to do. I am having some troubles with the formula however when I use it with my data. I should have used a more realistic example. My data is all strings and some have spaces and some do not in the string. [This sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jpSMgGISI_ohKCM6x0CimRNqlEL4URsvtTHXPwxLNL8/edit?usp=sharing) would better exemplify the data I am trying to collect into a matrix based on frequency of occurrence. Thank you so much for posting!

Comment: Also if it is any help, the data is coming from a google form where the 2 columns are questions that are "checkboxes".

Comment: I provided a new solution with some more comprehensible formulae. See if this helps ?

Comment: This is almost working. I think the issue is that some of the strings in the "Names" column have parenthesis in their text and it might be throwing off the formula interpretation. The strings with a parenthesis are the only ones that are not counting properly. I added the example "Chris (Jones)" to the second example sheet. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If the parenthesis are the only non-wordcharacters, the formulas I've updated (see second link in my answer) should be okay. Hope this helps ?